# Mocking Http Server responses using WireMock. FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, json, mocking, wiremock

Just started using wiremock and come across a scenario where i want to stub a GET request with a specific json response.

When appending the json to the expected response with;

```
.withBodyFile("product.json"))
```

I get the exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/test/resources/__files/product.json (No such file or directory).

The thing is I have the json file at this location.

Comment: This looks like a classpath issue but even if i use the full absolute path to the json file i still get the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running standalone, you should make sure that your json file is in src/test/resources/__files

Comment: What if it is not in that location ? How do make wiremock refer to the non standard location ?